# How can I resolve this JavaFX version error?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, frontend, fxml, scenebuilder

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=62887:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\UiPathBridge.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\rt.jar;F:\Super POS\out\production\Super POS;C:\Users\Buddika\Desktop\jfoenix-9.0.4.jar" AppInitializer
Jun 15, 2021 10:54:51 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.212

Answer (score 1):

> WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.212

Isn't that obvious? You created your FXML files with SceneBuilder 11 but you are trying to run that on an outdated JavaFX version 8. Just upgrade your JavaFX to something higher or equal to 11.

For the JavaFX 11 project samples setup, check the [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).